# PHP serialize - Store an image

Tags: php

Would it be possible to write a script that gave the user the ability to upload a file (Image gif,jpg,png) and the `serialize` it and store as text?

Essentially the user doesn't have any storage so wouldn't be able to upload a file and store as a file, but I've hijacked a profile field that can store user specific strings.

Any help appreciated?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to add yet another field to the table or create a new table (user_id,blobdata) ...in case you really want to store the image data within the database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can encode and decode binary data (like image data) to text with with [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) and [base64_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php).

Answer (score 1):

for storing it as text you have to remove all non-text chars using base64_encode not serialize.
in other hand - if your storage can receive binary data it's preferred to store image as is (like blob type in most of rdbms)